# Rock salt to kill weeds

Tags: weeds

I wanted to sprinkle rock salt around pool to kill weeds. Then put decorative stone on top. Will the rock salt affect my pool liner. I don't want to have the rock salt kill the weeds and destroy my pool liner at the same time.

Comment: Are you asking about killing weeds which would be very similar to this: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5216/can-salt-be-used-to-control-weeds-permanently or are you asking about preserving the pool liner which would be better asked in diy.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 5):

Rock salt kills weeds but is tough on soil, concrete and most plants.  Why not use something that will kill weeds and definitely does not endanger the pool liner?

Choices include

- [hot water](http://northernshade.ca/2009/07/18/killing-weeds-with-hot-water/)
- [propane weed burners](https://www.google.ca/search?q=weed%20burner&hl=en)
- [over strength vinegar](http://www.botanicalgarden.ubc.ca/forums/showthread.php?t=41632)

Any of these combined with applying them during the weeds growth period, usually in the spring, and filling any crack in the brick work with [polymeric sand](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/how-to-remove-the-weeds-and-avoid-them-growing-between-the-bricks/4707#4707) to reduce the area where new weed seeds can germinate will do a good safe job.